# VS Code Azure Automation Runbook Python Packages not recognized

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am unable to view my python packages through visual studio code. Verified on Azure portal that all the necessary packages are uploaded. I use python 3.8.10 on my local machine as the interpreter as these packages were verified with 3.8 runtime. I use the following link as a guide : (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/runbook-authoring-extension-for-vscode). quoted from the link under perquisites 'PowerShell modules and Python packages used by runbook must be locally installed on the machine to run the runbook locally.' I do have it locally stored as whl file, but do I have to configure the scripts to point it to the directory? my objective of using VS code is so that I can run the code locally quickly and do debugging instead of running it via the azure portal, which takes very long time.

Is it necessary to create virtual environment for my case?

[image: Python Packages not recognized]

[image: Python Packages uploaded to Azure Portal]

[image: Error Message in VS Code]

[image: Running runbook locally error]

[image: VS Code Terminal Directory]

Have tried making sure the Python interpreter is selected.

read the following links under limitations:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-authoring)

Comment: Try to install whl file with `pip install packagename.whl` and also create a virtual environment to make it work without conflicts. @Swann_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, yes you need to add the **Python Packages** resource of the Automation Account to run the runbook locally and it is also mentioned here in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-python-3#add-authentication-to-manage-azure-resources).

In my VSCode environment, I tried to execute below sample code and received the same error as you.

```
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
print ("Hello")
```

Then I used `pip install azure-mgmt-resource` command in the terminal to install the specific package.

[image]

*Note*: To install `whl` files, you can also use
`pip install <packagename>.whl` in the specific directory where the runbook is located of VSCode terminal.

Once you have installed the packages, check with below command whether it is installed accurately.

`pip list`

[image]

To work with Python runbooks locally, always use [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) as it avoids conflicts.

```
py -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate
```

Also restart the VSCode once everything has installed if still the issue persists.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your kind help with the explanation! @Jahnavi . May I ask further regarding virtual environment? 

1. In the document that you shared, we need to create virtual environment for different project. in this case, does the different projects refer to the project identifier '1610763723', which gets automatically created whenever there is a new runbook? 

example 1
PS C:\Users\vscodeAutomation\1610763723 

example 2
PS C:\Users\vscodeAutomation\1610763725

so do we run the 'py -m venv .venv' in the two project directory?

Comment: 2. what is the difference between using 'pip install azure-mgmt-resource' and 'pip install <packagename>.whl'. I use the former and i cant see the packages. is it hidden files?

Comment: `whl` files are something which installed automatically while you install a package. To avoid conflicts, I have given that as well. @Swann_

Comment: in my script, i have 'import time' statement to perform datetime operation. Do I have to add the .whl file to the azure automation account python packages? If So, could you let me know where i can download the .whl file? 

in the following link, 'time' package is not included as part of the default packages in azure..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/python-3-packages?tabs=py3%2Csa-mi#default-python-packages